# what is the meaning of this quote by Ralph W Emerson?

Tags: quotes

“There are many things of which a wise man might wish to be ignorant.”

Comment: Even seemingly wise people may have flaws and refuse to see reason (facts) in specific cases which conflict with their outlook/beliefs.

Comment: @alwayslearning- Hmmm.  I'm not convinced of that one.

Comment: You've never heard the expression "Too much information!"?

Comment: (Let's say that you have just seen, up close, the results of a traffic accident where someone's brains were literally scattered on the pavement.  Wouldn't you like to just forget you ever saw that?)

Comment: This probably belongs in Philosophy SE.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to read the full quote:

> There are many things of which a wise man might wish to be ignorant,
>   and these are such. Shun them as you would the secrets of the
>   undertaker and the butcher.

Which reminds one of the famous saying:

> Laws are like sausages. It’s better not to see them being made.
>   http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780191826719.001.0001/q-oro-ed4-00001699#.WA2KXKG-wxQ

In other words, there are things you don't want to know.

---

The [article](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/emerson/4957107.0010.001/1:8?rgn=div1;view=fulltext) from which this is taken is titled *Demonology*:

> THE name Demonology covers dreams, omens, coincidences, luck,
>   sortilege, magic and other experiences

The author warns the reader against what today we would call [New Age beliefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Age) and goes on to say that such things are best left to the Devil:

> The best are never demoniacal or magnetic; leave this limbo to the
>   Prince of the power of the air.

Comment: I was tempted to answer, but based on your answer, I won't. +1.

Comment: @RichardKayser - That OK.  We didn't want to know anyway.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean by *we*, kemosabe?